# Rounding Integration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, .net-core, rounding

I would like to write a code which support me rounding for values using decimals.
So, how do I write such code?

```
Example 1:

(1) var mainValue = 1.2356 , decimals = 3 ===> 1.236
(2) var mainValue = 1.2356 , decimals = 2 ===> 1.24
(3) var mainValue = 1.2356 , decimals = 1 ===> 1.2

Example 2:
(1) var mainValue = 1.3210 , decimals = 3 ===> 1.321
(2) var mainValue = 1.3210 , decimals = 2 ===> 1.32
(3) var mainValue = 1.3210 , decimals = 1 ===> 1.3

Example 3:
(1) var mainValue = 1.0325 , decimals = 3 ===> 1.033
(2) var mainValue = 1.0325 , decimals = 2 ===> 1.03
(3) var mainValue = 1.0325 , decimals = 1 ===> 1.0

Example 4:
(1) var mainValue = 2.3912 , decimals = 3 ===> 2.391
(2) var mainValue = 2.3912 , decimals = 2 ===> 2.39
(3) var mainValue = 2.3912 , decimals = 1 ===> 2.4

Example 5:
(1) var mainValue = 5.4565 , decimals = 3 ===> 5.457
(2) var mainValue = 5.4565 , decimals = 2 ===> 5.46
(3) var mainValue = 5.4565 , decimals = 1 ===> 5.5
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, what exactly is the question?
and what is the result you get when using `Math.Round`?

Comment: Please show what you´ve tried and how this didn´t work for you. Otherwise chances are high answers here won´t help you. What if anyone of us would give you a solution you already tried out yourself? I doubt that would help you, so please be so kind to provide more information about what you have problems with.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Did you start to implement your rounding method? And it doesn't work? Then we'd need to see the code and the expected results and what happens instead.

Comment: I was trying 

`Math.Round(5.6,1,MidpointRounding.EvenTo);` instead of 

`Math.Round(5.6,1,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: [MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2) is your friend. Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W3mNJv) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you're missing the `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` parameter from your calls to `Math.Round()`. Without that, you will get strange rounding results as it rounds to the nearest EVEN number (so called "Banker's Rounding").

Try this code; it gives your expected results:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            round(1.2356, 3);
            round(1.2356, 2);
            round(1.2356, 1);

            round(1.3210, 3);
            round(1.3210, 2);
            round(1.3210, 1);

            round(1.0325, 3);
            round(1.0325, 2);
            round(1.0325, 1);

            round(2.3912, 3);
            round(2.3912, 2);
            round(2.3912, 1);

            round(5.4565, 3);
            round(5.4565, 2);
            round(5.4565, 1);
        }

        static void round(double value, int decimals)
        {
            double result = Math.Round(value, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            Console.WriteLine($"round({value}, {decimals}) = {result}");
        }
    }
}
```